# Deleting association between two objects

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I create application in Spring, which stores albums, musicians and bands. Album can contain multiple bands and musicians. I created association between `Album` and `Band`/`Musician`. Jet I am unable to delete it. I don't want to delete objects, just the association. I tried to send REST PUT request and setting `musicians` and `bands` to `null` on `Album` site, yet nothing happens:

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Lulu",
        "bands": null,
        "musicians": null,
        "duration": {
            "hours": 1,
            "minutes": 20,
            "seconds": 4
        },
        "releaseDate": "31/10/2011",
        "coverPath": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/40/Lou_Reed_and_Metallica_-_Lulu.jpg",
        "spotifyPath": null
}
```

I have created following class and method to link `Album` and `Musician`, yet I am unable to "unlink" them:

```
@RestController
public class AlbumMusicianController {
    @Autowired
    AlbumRepository albumRepository;
    @Autowired
    MusicianRepository musicianRepository;

    @Transactional
    @PostMapping("/musician/{musicianId}/album/{albumId}")
    public List<Album> associate(@PathVariable Long musicianId, @PathVariable Long albumId) {
        Album album = this.albumRepository.findById(albumId).orElseThrow(() -> new MissingResourceException("Album",
                "Album", albumId.toString()));

        return this.musicianRepository.findById(musicianId).map((musician) -> { musician.getAlbums().add(album);
            return this.musicianRepository.save(musician).getAlbums();
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new MissingResourceException("Musician", "Musician", musicianId.toString()));
    }
}
```

Would be thankful for any help.

Below are necessary sources.

`Album` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="album")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Album {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Band.class, mappedBy = "albums")
    @JsonSerialize(using = BandsSerializer.class)
    private List<Band> bands;
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Musician.class, mappedBy = "albums")
    @JsonSerialize(using = MusiciansSerializer.class)
    private List<Musician> musicians;
    @Embedded
    @Column(name="duration")
    private Duration duration;
    @Column(name="releasedate")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd/MM/yyyy", timezone="CET")
    private Date releaseDate;
    @Column(name="coverpath")
    private String coverPath;
    @Column(name="spotifypath")
    private String spotifyPath;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
    public Date getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }
    public void setReleaseDate(Date releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }
    public String getCoverPath() {
        return coverPath;
    }
    public void setCoverPath(String coverPath) {
        this.coverPath = coverPath;
    }
    public String getSpotifyPath() {
        return spotifyPath;
    }
    public void setSpotifyPath(String spotifyPath) {
        this.spotifyPath = spotifyPath;
    }
    public List<Band> getBands() {
        return bands;
    }
    public void setBands(List<Band> bands) {
        this.bands = bands;
    }
    public List<Musician> getMusicians() {
        return musicians;
    }
    public void setMusicians(List<Musician> musicians) {
        this.musicians = musicians;
    }
}
```

`Musician` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="musician")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Musician {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;
    @Column(name="birthdate")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd/MM/yyyy", timezone="CET")
    private Date birthDate;
    @Column(name="picturepath")
    private String picturePath;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "album_musician",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "album_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "musician_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Album> albums;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }
    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
    public String getPicturePath() {
        return picturePath;
    }
    public void setPicturePath(String picturePath) {
        this.picturePath = picturePath;
    }
    public List<Album> getAlbums() {
        return albums;
    }
    public void setAlbums(List<Album> albums) {
        this.albums = albums;
    }
}
```

`Band` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="band")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Band {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="picturepath")
    private String picturePath;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "album_band",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "album_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "band_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @JsonSerialize(using = AlbumsSerializer.class)
    private List<Album> albums;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPicturePath() {
        return picturePath;
    }
    public void setPicturePath(String picturePath) {
        this.picturePath = picturePath;
    }
    public List<Album> getAlbums() {
        return albums;
    }
    public void setAlbums(List<Album> albums) {
        this.albums = albums;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your JSON body I'm going to assume you were sending a PUT request for the Album entity. There were two things that I found missing that got it to work for me after adjusting. I'm not sure if you were avoiding using them for one reason or another.

- Cascade rules to cascade changes from Album to its relations.
- Proper entity mapping for the join table from Album to its relations.

  - Not really sure why this was an issue - Hibernate did not seem to throw any exceptions related to this at execution time, but it did not seem to persist things correctly.

Here is an adjusted relation definition for Album's relation to Musician.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="album_musician", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "musician_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "album_id",
        referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Musician> musicians;
```

In this format, I was able to cascade changes from Album to Musician. You will have to do something similar for the Band entity to cascade operations from Album to Band.

Comment: After I added annotation I get error: ```org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like @JoinTable or @JoinColumn: com.musesite.model.Album.musicians```

Comment: Notice that I have removed `mappedBy` in the `@ManyToMany` annotation.